# How to hackishly make a scroll bar

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, standards, ie8-compatibility-mode

There was a hack, such as:

```
<DIV style="HEIGHT: 148px; overflow: auto;">
<DIV style="HEIGHT: 579px">
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

Bang, there is a scroll bar 148px tall. However, in ie8 standards mode this no longer works. I can switch to ie7 compat mode, but this breaks other things.

Does anyone know some other hack?

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but I don't see how the rendering of the code that you show above is supposed to have changed. What happens in IE8? Can you add `&nbsp;` to the inner DIV?

Comment: This has been downvoted twice? I want to know who these lazy, can't bother to comment downvoters are...

Comment: @jball yeah, I don't understand either

Comment: Well, it is kind of mixed in, with other code, I am probably missing some connection.

Comment: +1, simply because I think this is a valid question and shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: Could be the lack of a width?

Comment: Could be ie8 doesn't like the caps in the css.

Comment: It did have width of zero for the inner div

Comment: @Stephan I sure hope so.

Answer (score 0):

Can't confirm. This works just fine in IE8 here: http://jsbin.com/ubano5